# The method of retrieving a list of data in firebase using random generate key? Thanks

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, random

My Database Structure:

[image: My database structure]

Hi,I'm currently working on Android Studio project. How do I retrieve a list of data in firebase with random generate key? For example, I need to retrieve the institute name, address and phone. I'm having the random generated id, how do I reference it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.  This one is a bit vague.  For example, you don't even specify what language you are using.  Its generally best to show what you've already tried, as there is excellent [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) about how to do retrieval by a known key.

Comment: The document id is the name of the document.  db.collections('foo').doc(someId).get()

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the `name`, `address` and `phone` try the following:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String name = ds.child("instituteName").getValue(String.class);
           String phone   = ds.child("institutePhone").getValue(String.class);
           String address   = ds.child("instituteAddress").getValue(String.class);
     } 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

First add a reference to the root node then add a for loop to iterate inside the random if and retrieve the data.